# AWS RDS error Symlinks in pg_tblspc broken

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

while querying data in pgadmin, I am getting below error

ERROR: could not read symbolic link "pg_tblspc/53605151": NO such file or directory.

I am using Aurora postgres.

Let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Your database is corrupted. Ask Amazon for help.

Answer (score 0):

To check for missing tablespaces, run the following query after logging in to your Aurora PostgreSQL instance using the AWS CLI or a PostgreSQL client. Verify the existence of the tablespace that the error message specifies.

```
SELECT oid, datname, pg_tablespace_location(oid) AS tablespace_location
FROM pg_database;
```

Noe use the command under to establish a connection to your Aurora PostgreSQL instance. The tablespace's current location can be seen by running this command. Verify that the directory is present and has the required rights.

```
SELECT pg_tablespace_location('53605151');
```

The symbolic link may need to be recreated or repaired if it is damaged or missing. The command below can be used to recreate the symbolic link if it is broken:

```
SELECT pg_tablespace_location(oid) FROM pg_tablespace WHERE oid = '53605151';
```

Next, create the symbolic link:

```
SELECT pg_tablespace_location(oid) FROM pg_tablespace WHERE oid = '53605151';
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Hi Maimooma, unable to create symbolic link, with above command . I can able to see the location for one of the tablespace, is this possible to create with symbolic link with available location?